# Tomcat deployment creates 2 folders from single war file?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my developed `TestMyApplication.war` file to tomcat. Problem: on startup tomcat will create 2 folders in `webapps`: `/TestMyApplication` and `/test`. This results in errors as then 2 applications are trying to start. The content of these folders is identically.

Why could this happen? And how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference: The `path` attribute in `server.xml` was pointing to `/test`, whereas the war name was different. That caused the duplicate deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In server.xml file, if  path attribute and docBase has different values then we 
face two folder creation issue.I resolved same issue by fixing it.